# Load specific ID range on MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, http, items

How do I load a specific ID range of items from MySQL?
Loading the first 10 items is done so:

```
SELECT * FROM Test LIMIT 10
```

But I want to load, for example, ID 10 to 25. How do I make this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LIMIT clause accepts one or two arguments: offset and count:

- The offset specifies the offset of the first row to return. The offset of the first row is 0, not 1.
- The count specifies maximum number of rows to return.

Read: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

```
SELECT * FROM Test LIMIT 10, 15
```

Comment: No, `10,15` select `10,11,12...25`; `10,25` select `10,11,12...35`

Answer (score 1):

you can give the limit clause two parameters, starting row, and number of rows

```
SELECT * FROM Test LIMIT 10, 15
```